# Install formula missing from homebrew list

Tags: github, formula, homebrew

I am trying to install astrometry.net for which there exists a formula, but the formula isn't in my list of formulas even after performing

```
brew update
```

The formula can be found at this page. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/385

I cant figure out what I need to do to add the formula to the list. I can't just create a new file and copy and paste. That doesn't work. I am a n00b when it comes to github and homebrew.

What is the command to add a specific formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
brew tap homebrew/science
```

before you can install packages from the repository.